# Enabling Swagger (OpenAPI 2.0 Metadata) for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, openapi

I'm currently following the azure documentation for enabling swagger documentation for azure functions but I'm currently stuck at [Enabling API Definition Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-api-definition-getting-started#enable)

Do I need to change something within the Azure Function App to be able to see these preview items? I can't see anything in the azure documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Definition Tab by default seems to be hidden even though the documentation tells us to just click the tab.

However if we go to *Platform feature* and then click *API definition*.

[image]

We magically get the tab to appear!

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've reached out to the owner to update the stale documentation.

Comment: I think API definition feature doesn't support passing `bearer token` and creating request body automatically. Lot of manual work still needed to make it work.